# How to read the APN settings 4.2

Tags: android

How to read the APN Settingsin android version 4.2 programmatically.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Android versions 4.0+ no longer allow 3rd party apps to access APN settings.

Comment: are you sure that it will even not work on 4.0 and 4.1 also.?